# Whitespace - Not printing second character

Tags: whitespace-language

s = space; l = line break; t = tab

```
ssstsssttsl
tl
ssl
sssttsssstl
tl
ssl
```

This only prints `F` and not `a`. I am not very certain about stacks and it is probably something to do with that.

Answer (score 1):

I put your code into this online IDE: https://whitespace.kauaveel.ee/

It includes an on-the-fly disassembler, which is nice.

As is, your code produces an "*Unexpected EOF*" error. This is because of the last linebreak (`l`). Removing that gives

```
  push 70
  printc
label_0:
  printc
```

from the disassembler. I.e. what you thought was your second `push` is actually a `label` instruction.

This is because the `printc` instruction is actually just `tlss`. You have an extra `l` after that, which combined with the following two spaces forms `lss` (`label`).

Fixed code:

```
s s s t s s s t t   s l
t   l
s s s s s t t   s s s s t   l
t   l
s s
```